# When I clicked notification run in background it's always call MainActivity , How I can call my WebVIew

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I clicked notification run in background it's always call MainActivity , I sent url from Firebase Cloud Messing when I click when I'm in application it can open WebView that I create but if I clicked when close application it's always call MainActivity.
No have any error and I think it not call any if-clause .
please help and sorry for my english .

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public MyFirebaseMessagingService() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);


        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() <= 0){

            String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

            MessageHelper.displayMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, body);
        }

        if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0){

            String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            String url = remoteMessage.getData().get("url");

            MessageHelper.displayNotification(getApplicationContext(), title, body, url);
        }
    }

}
```

public class MessageHelper {

```
public static void displayMessage(Context context, String title, String body){

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewsFragment.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            0,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(body)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    notificationManagerCompat.notify(0, builder.build());
}

public static void displayNotification(Context context, String title, String body, String url){

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewsWebView.class);
    intent.putExtra("id", url);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(body)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    notificationManagerCompat.notify(1 , builder.build());
}
```

}

```
`
```

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to read incoming intent `OnCreate()`

```java
Intent read_int = getIntent();
Log.d("INTENT", read_int.toUri(0));
```

Then you can break down the incoming Uri request with:

```java
String uri = read_int.getStringExtra("uri");   // your data sent over FCM
```

And then condition, what activity you want to launch:

```java
if(uri != null){
   Intent openWV = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, MyWebViewActivity.class);
   openWV.putExtra("open_url", uri);   // optional parameters
   CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(openWV);
}
```